# Angular js controller with factory service

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to call a factory service from a controller that it's been located on a different js file (an example will be nice), or the controller and factory service have to be on the same file ?

Thanks

Comment: yes. it's possible

Comment: Another question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518419/angularjs-modules-and-external-controllers

Answer (score 1):

You can include both scripts in index.html and then use the service in your controller:

index.html

```
<script src="js/pictures/picture.service.js"></script>
<script src="js/pictures/controllers/pictures.js"></script>
```

Here is the service picture.service.js:

```
(() => {
    angular.module('gallery').factory('Picture', ['$http', 'Upload', function ($http, Upload) {

        return {
            all: () => {
                return $http.get('/api/pictures');
            },
            findById: (id) => {
                return $http.get(`/api/pictures/${id}`);
            },
            create: (picture) => {
                return Upload.upload({
                    url: '/api/pictures/create',
                    data: picture
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
})();
```

Here is the controller where I am injecting the service:

```
(() => {
    angular.module('gallery').controller('Pictures', ['Picture', function (Picture) {
        let pictures = this;
        // You might want to use .then instead of .success (deprecated)
        Picture.all().success((data) => {
            pictures.pictures = data;
        });

    }]);
})();
```

Here is an example github repo with a simple MEAN stack project.
https://github.com/NikolayKolibarov/MEAN-Simple-Gallery