# I have a problem with my js file using AngularJS: "Error: [ng:areq]"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, service, controller

Im doing a formation of AngularJS and when i start the application it gives me this error everytime. Im looking at this for a long time and i cant find out. I have already check the names of the files and the modules. Any ideas?

Error: http://prntscr.com/nd45d2

File: app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
    ...
    <div ng-view> </div>

    @if(Config::get('app.debug'))
        <script src="{{ asset('build/js/vendor/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('build/js/vendor/angular.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('build/js/vendor/angular-route.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('build/js/vendor/angular-resource.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('build/js/vendor/angular-animate.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('build/js/vendor/angular-messages.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('build/js/vendor/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('build/js/vendor/navbar.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('build/js/vendor/angular-cookies.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('build/js/vendor/query-string.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('build/js/vendor/angular-oauth2.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('build/js/vendor/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js') }}"></script>

        <script src="{{asset('build/js/app.js')}}"></script>

        <!-- Controllers -->
        <script src="{{asset('build/js/controllers/login.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('build/js/controllers/home.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('build/js/controllers/client/clientList.js')}}"></script>

        <!-- Services -->
        <script src="{{asset('build/js/services/client.js')}}"></script>

    @else
        <script src="{{ elixir('js/all.js') }}"></script>
    @endif

    <!-- Routes -->
    <script src="{{asset('build/js/app.js')}}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

File: app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'angular-oauth2', 'ui.bootstrap.tpls', 'app.controllers', 'app.services']);

angular.module('app.controllers', ['ngMessages', 'angular-oauth2']);
angular.module('app.services', ['ngResource']);

app.provider('appConfig', function () {
   var config = {
       baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000'
   };

   return{
       config: config,
       $get: function(){
           return config;
       }
   }
});

app.config([
    '$routeProvider', 'OAuthProvider', 'OAuthTokenProvider', 'appConfigProvider',
    function($routeProvider, OAuthProvider, OAuthTokenProvider, appConfigProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/login',{
            templateUrl: 'build/views/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginController'
        })
        .when('/home',{
            templateUrl: 'build/views/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        })
        .when('/clients',{
            templateUrl: 'build/views/client/list.html',
            controller: 'ClientListController'
        });
    OAuthProvider.configure({
        baseUrl: appConfigProvider.config.baseUrl,
        clientId: 'app',
        clientSecret: 'secret', //optional
        grantPath: 'oauth/access_token' //'oauth/token'
    });
    OAuthTokenProvider.configure({
        name: 'token',
        option:{
            secure: false
        }
    });
}]);

app.run(['$rootScope', '$window', 'OAuth', function ($rootScope, $window, OAuth) {
    $rootScope.$on('oauth:error', function (event, rejection) {
        // Ignore 'invalid_grant' error - should be catched on 'LoginController
        if('invalid_grant' === rejection.data.error){
            return;
        }

        // Refresh token when a 'invalid_token' error occurs
        if('invalid_token' === rejection.data.error){
            return OAuth.getRefreshToken();
        }

        return $window.location.href = '/login?error_reason=' + rejection.data.error;
    });
}]);
```

File: home.js

```
angular.module('app.controllers')
    .controller('HomeController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the error happens because `build/js/app.js` is loaded twice:

- First time it is loaded before controllers
- For the second time it is loaded after `<!-- Routes -->` comment.

Try to remove the second load of `build/js/app.js` to see if it's the root cause.

Comment: @Dacriber My pleasure

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at the console it actually says in there "HomeController is not a function"

My guess is that (because I can't see you've included it anywhere), you've forgotten to define your controllers in Angular.

I've never used Angular (or any of those kinds of frameworks) so I could be mistaken, but after a bit of poking around the net I came across this:

```
   function studentController($scope) {
      $scope.student = {
         firstName: "Mahesh",
         lastName: "Parashar",

         fullName: function() {
            var studentObject;
            studentObject = $scope.student;
            return studentObject.firstName + " " + studentObject.lastName;
         }
      };
   }
```

Comment: Thats not it, but thank you for looking into it. Btw u can se on this anwer how to create controllers in another file.
[link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518419/angularjs-modules-and-external-controllers)